React Native: Vector Icons Not Rendering
I'm currently following this article's tutorial from React Navigation, using these versions of their packages:
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",

They're imported (in addition to Ionicons used in my code below) as such:
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

The icons I'm using from the Ionicon library (as outlined here not rendering in this part of the code (copied directly and only slightly edited from their implementation for my 3 pages):

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({route}) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'home'
                : 'home-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Appearance') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'color-palette'
                : 'color-palette-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Quotes') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'chatbox-ellipses'
                : 'chatbox-ellipses-outline';
            } else {
              // default if undefined:
              iconName = focused
                ? 'home'
                : 'home-outline';
            }
            
            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'blue',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        })}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Appearance" component={AppearanceScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Quotes" component={QuotesScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

This is what I'm seeing on my Android simulator:

What I've tried is to use the exact code from the aforementioned article, as such:
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'ios-information-circle'
                : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-list' : 'ios-list-outline';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

However, they render as question marks:


You need to install react-native-vector-icons package and do platform specific tasks for iOS and Android respectively.

Thanks. I had already installed the react-native-vector-icons package, so following that Android link is what fixed my issue.

React Native Tab Navigation is using react-native-vector-icons library for icons. Before import you have to install it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons
Here you are using Ionicons icons. So you have to get icon names from
https://ionic.io/ionicons

Already installed through npm i react-native-vector-icons.

1- download all files files
2-add all in android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
like that

3- make sure add react-native-config.js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-vector-icons': {platforms: {ios: null}},
  },
};

4- install react-native-vector-icons
yarn add react-native-vector-icons 

npm install --save react-native-vector-icons


Try removing node_modules and package-lock.json
and fresh install node modules
npm i
This above worked for me
